# Background image issue with speed website

Tags: php, html, css

Hello i'm trying to solve issues with website speed optimizations but i'm newbie to that point.

I have issue with background image loading largest contentful element using: This is the largest contentful element painted within the viewport.

It shows me the problems is here: `<div class="image-layer" style="background-image: url`
so i found out that code and check it out

```php
public static function getHomeBannerSliderHtml(){
        $objData= HomeBannerModel::where(['status'=>'enable','location'=>'homePageBanner'])->orderBy('order','ASC')->get();
        $htmlContent="";
        foreach($objData as $val){
            if($val->start_date >= date('Y-m-d') && $val->end_date <= date('Y-m-d')){
                HomeBannerModel::where('id', $val->id)->update(['status' => 'disable']);
                continue;
            }
            $htmlContent .= '<div class="slide-item">
            <div class="image-layer" style="background-image: url('.url('storage/app/home-banners/' . $val->banner_image).');"></div>
            <div class="auto-container">
               <div class="content-box">
                  <h1>'.$val->banner_title.'
                  </h1>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>';
        }
        return $htmlContent;
    }
```

```css
.banner-section .banner-carousel .slide-item .image-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 6000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 6000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 6000ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 6000ms linear;
    transition: all 6000ms linear
}

.banner-section .banner-carousel .active .slide-item .image-layer {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15)
}

.banner-section-two .slide-item .image-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 112px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 6000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 6000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 6000ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 6000ms linear;
    transition: all 6000ms linear
}

.banner-section-two .slide-item .image-layer {
    top: 0px !important;
}
```

Can someone help me how to improve it to load fast?

I tried to set up widht and height options but still the same.

Comment: Make the images smaller?

Comment: not an option. This is background image that is displayed in top header position.

Comment: I deal with this by using an absolute positioned img element, rather than a background image. the img element has srcset and sizes attributes which contain a number of presentation options for various screen sizes.  [Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

Comment: maybe can someone help by adding lazy load is it going to fix the issue? how to do it this way

Comment: any advices how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Remember to convert your photos/images to **JPEG/JPG** format with medium compression.
Crop each of your images to obtain images suitable for all uses (responsive images).

- This will reduce the weight of your photos/images,
- You'll also reduce the **loading time** of your pages thanks to appropriate photos/images,
- Then use the **responsive** properties to adapt your photos/images as you wish in your page.

Answer (score -2):

Compress the image to smaller size, Use tools like Tinypng. you can upload the image in tinypng website & make it smaller in size withough losing the image quality